# Formatting a JSON from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a Pandas df that needs to be a json.
Code for my Dataframe:

```
final_df=final_df[['form_number', 'form_title', 'min_year', 'max_year']]

final_df.head()
```

I used the following codes to turn df into json:

```
import json
result = final_df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
json.dumps(parsed,sort_keys=True)
```

but I am getting this:

'[{"form_number": "Form 1000", "form_title": "Ownership Certificate", "max_year": 2016, "min_year": 1981}, {"form_number": "Form 1023", "form_title": "Application for Recognition of Exemption Under Section 501(c)(3) of the Internal Revenue Code", "max_year": 2017, "min_year": 2004}, {"form_number": "Form 1023-EZ", "form_title": "Streamlined Application for Recognition of Exemption Under Section 501(c)(3) of the Internal Revenue Code", "max_year": 2014, "min_year": 2014}, {"form_number": "Form 1023-Interactive", "form_title": "Interactive version of Form 1023, Application for Recognition of Exemption Under Section 501(c)(3) of the Internal Revenue Code", "max_year": 2017, "min_year": 2006},

This is the final format i need to end up with:

```
[
     
    {
        
        "form_number": "Form 1000", 
        
        "form_title": "Ownership Certificate", 
        
        "max_year": 2016, 
        
        "min_year": 1981
      
        }
      ...
]
```

I am having some trouble getting there.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but those look the same except for extra whitespace. You could use a json pretty printer for that.

Comment: `parsed = json.loads(result)` should be used if `result` was a strict not a `dict / list` (objects).  So you are trying to convert objects to objects with a function that is for converting a string to objects

Comment: try adding `indent=4` inside the **json.dumps()** where 4 is the number of spaces.

Comment: Thank you, Everyone! I figured it out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's solved by OP, and no answer was posted.